# Can I refer items inside ngRepeat by index, not name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I am looking for, is to replace this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="travel in travelList">
   <td>
      {{travel.travelerId}}
   </td>
   <td>
      {{travel.travelerName}}
   </td>
</tr>
```

With something like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="travel in travelList">    
   <td>
      {{travel[0]}}    
   </td>    
   <td>
      {{travel[1]}}    
   </td> 
</tr>
```

The data stracture for Travel inside TravelList is this:

```
public class Travel
{
        public int TravelId { get; set; }
        public string TravelerId { get; set; }
        public string TravelerName { get; set; }
        public string TravelerEmail { get; set; }
        public string RecruiterId { get; set; }
        public List<Itinerary> Itinerary { get; set; }
}
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. That's not how JS objects work. `someObj[key]` is valid syntax, but unless you explicitly set a value for a key (like `someObj[0] = 'foo'`) then the result is undefined.

If you want to iterate over the properties of each `travel`, you will need a second `ng-repeat` like `<td ng-repeat='(key, value) in travel'>{{travel[key]}}</td>`, but then you might as well just use `{{value}}` unless you are hoping to use the keys as labels in a header row or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use `$index` (created inside the `ngRepeat` scope)

```
{{travelList[$index]}}
```

Comment: @superconsultant -- Made an edit, you should be referencing your actual list, and not the item

Comment: This way it displays JSON string for the item with all it's sub items, but I need to be able to loop through sub items of an item.

Comment: @superconsultant -- Maybe you should post your data structure... you can always do a repeat inside a repeat.

Comment: I apologize if I am being unclear in my question, I just added the data structure above. When I loop through TravelList, I am accessing Travel attributes of each Travel item in the Travel list like this `travel.travelerId` or `travel.travelerName,` nut instead I want to address the Travel attributes trough the attribute index not an attribute name, something like `travel[index of traveler id]` in Travel's collection of attributes and so on.